# bind9 (named) does not start in multi-threaded mode

Tags: multicore, named, bind9

From the bind9 man page, I understand that the named process starts one worker thread per CPU if it was able to determine the number of CPUs. If its unable to determine, a single worker thread is started. 
My question is how does it calculate the number of CPUs? I presume by CPU, it means cores. The Linux machine I work is customized and has kernel 2.6.34 and does not support `lscpu` or `nproc` utilities. named is starting a single thread even if i give -n 4 option. Is there any other way to force named to start multiple threads?

Thanks in advance.